# How to select the HTML table's 2nd column to 5th column in the 2nd row?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know that

```
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)
```

is used to select the 2nd column of the 2nd row.

1. How to select between 2nd and 5th column of the 2nd row?
2. How to select all the columns starting from the 2nd column of the 2nd row ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Some images here showing the desired result here would be ***very*** useful.

Comment: The question seems fairly self-explanatory to me. I'd consider a selector and a description of said selector to be the shortest code necessary to describe the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. How to select between 2nd and 5th column of the 2nd row?**

```css
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

**2. How to select all the columns starting from the 2nd column of the 2nd row ?**

```css
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(n+2) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>four</td>
    <td>five</td>
    <td>six</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First one is for the first question, the second is for the second question

```
tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+5){
    color: pink;
}

tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(n+2){
    color: pink;
}
```

See Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ncqmycz7/